# Hibernate -- cascading on @OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hibernate-onetomany, object-relational-model

I have a `@OneToMany` relationship between 
`Table1` and `Table2` in Hibernate. 
`Table1` is the owner, and the relationship is one-directional-- i haven't mapped 
`Table2` back to `Table1`.

So, as part of this, I defined a `Collection` of `Table2` 
instances for this `@OneToMany` mapping. 
and I'm cascading-all.

In this "scenario", i'm looking to add a collection of 
`Table2` instances, say `table2_a`, `table2_b` and `table2_c` 
as related to a `Table1` object, say `table1`.

Is there a way to do this insertion on saving the owner class instance, `table1`, 
and thus having the dependent class instances `table2_a`, `table2_b` and `table2_c` saved on cascade?
When i attempt to do this, i'm getting an error that

```
Duplicate entry '23' for key ...
```

Hibernate is attempting to save all of `table2_a`, `table2_b` and `table2_c` 
on the same `Table2` key value generated for the corresponding `Table1` instance in the session. 
So, how do i put to use the "Many" side of `@OneToMany` here ?

Is there a way to do this insertion with the uni-directional mapping 
as is-- without mapping also `Table2` to `Table1`, on `@ManyToOne`, for the other side of the relationship?
I'm looking to keep the tables light.

The code is working on insertion of a single `Table2` instance in the collection, and everything else is fine.

//===========================

EDIT: the relevant parts of the code:

the relationship defined in `Table1`-- the entity class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Table2> table2Inst = new ArrayList<>();
// getter & setter
```

the code doing the save in pojo:

```
    table1 = (Table1)session.get(Table1.class, theId);

    if ( table1!=null ) {
        table1.getTable2Inst().addAll(contactsList);
        session.saveOrUpdate(table1);  
    }
```

Note: i'm defining it all on the entity class. there's nothing in mapping files.

Comment: post your sample code about how you save those table

Answer (score 0):

did't you need to add `mappedBy = "table1Id"` or something in that one to many? like this.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "table1Id");//table1Id is foreign key of table1 in table2
private Collection<Table2> table2Inst = new ArrayList<>();
```

and did you make sure that `contactsList` is composed from all new object `new table2()`?